# Python stock scraping script not pulling back pricing data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stocks

So I've been working on a simple script that pulls stock symbols from a .txt file in the projects main directory and I just can't seem for it to bring back the pricing data.  It works if I manually input them into a string array but when it comes to pulling from the file i just doesn't want to return the prices.

```
import urllib
import re

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
newsymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i = 0

while i<len(newsymbollist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert_gs_ctrl1&fr=&type=2button&s=" +symbolslist[i] +""
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_184_' +newsymbolslist[i] +'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "The price of", newsymbolslist[i] ," is ", price
    i+=1
```

I could really use some help because it doesn't give any errors in the shell as to why.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the question here? What is your current output?

Comment: Could you provide a few lines of your _txt_ as well, the output you get and what you want to receive?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: There are a number of things you could be doing to improve this, but here it's actually a simple typo. The `span` ID prefix is `yfs_l84_` - note the letter "l", not the number "1" in "l84".

Comment: When it runs it will just print out "The price of AAPL is []"

Comment: That's the only symbol in the file as of right now but i've tried with many others and it doesn't seem to work with any

Answer (score 0):

By implementing the modification provided by @Linus Gustav Larsson Thiel in the comments and another one concerning the `regex` your code returns correct results. Please note the `lowercase()` in the regex, since the source includes lowercase symbols:

```
i = 0

while i < len(newsymbolslist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert_gs_ctrl1&fr=&type=2button&s=" +newsymbolslist[i]
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' +newsymbolslist[i].lower() +'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = pattern.findall(htmltext)
    print "The price of", newsymbolslist[i] ," is ", price
    i+=1
```

With a static list for testing purposes `['AAPL','GOOGL','MSFT']` I receive the following output:

```
The price of AAPL  is  ['98.53']
The price of GOOGL  is  ['733.07']
The price of MSFT  is  ['52.30']
```

---

If you want to, you might simplify your code as well:

```
baseurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert_gs_ctrl1&fr=&type=2button&s="

for symbol in newsymbolslist:
    url = baseurl + symbol
    source = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    regex = re.compile('<span id="yfs_l84_' + symbol.lower() + '">(.+?)</span>')
    price = regex.findall(source)[0]
    print "The price of", symbol, "is", price
```

The `for ... in ...` loop eliminates the need for a counter variable and since `findall()` returns a list of matches (while you only expect one) you might attach `[0]` to display the containing string and not the list with a single element.

This will return the following:

```
The price of AAPL is 98.53
The price of GOOGL is 733.07
The price of MSFT is 52.30
```